# Ruby on Rails - Need to Read XML File into an Array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, xml, iteration

I am using Ruby on Rails and need to read the contents of an xml file into an array?

I pulled the data from an API using the following:

```
     uri = URI.parse("myAPIurl.com&show=storeID,name")
    http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
 request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)
response = http.request(request)
```

Looking for a lean method to iterate this xml file into an array using Ruby on Rails.

Answer (score 2):

For simple use cases you can use:

```
xml = <<-XML
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <hash>
      <foo type="integer">1</foo>
      <bar type="integer">2</bar>
    </hash>
XML

hash = Hash.from_xml(xml)
# => {"hash"=>{"foo"=>1, "bar"=>2}}
```

[Hash - Ruby on Rails](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html#method-i-from_xml)

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Nokogiri](http://www.nokogiri.org/) gem. It's super easy to use, the website has some nice examples.

```
require 'open-uri'
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open("myAPIurl.com&show=storeID,name"))
```

you can then query your document using xpath or css selectors. It then returns a NodeSet that you can iterate over like you would do with an array

Hope it helps